# making two containers in a row

Tags: html, css, sass

May I ask how to fix this? I need the second container to be at the bottom of the first container, and I do not know how to solve it. I have used `display: flex` but it seems it does not feel right and applicable in two containers, that is why I am having a trouble on how to fix it:

https://jsfiddle.net/0nv2oLqy/1/

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 350px;
}

aside ul {
  padding-top: 5%;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

aside a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: $font1;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

aside a:hover {
  color: $color1;
}

.first {
  margin: 50px;
}

.first a {
  background-color: #ebe0dd;
  padding: 4px;
}

.line {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $color5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="content">
  <aside class="d-none d-md-block">
    <ul>
      <li class="first"><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">To Pay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">To Ship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">To Receive</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cancelled</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>



  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-5 item1" height="20">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" width="50">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10 my-2">
        <h5>Charlotte Folk</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>To Pay</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" width="80">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10">
        <h6>CFXXI Sweater</h6>
        <h6>Large</h6>
        <h6>x1</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>P990</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg text-center bottom1"><a href="#">Contact Seller</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-5 item2" height="20">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" width="50">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10 my-2">
        <h5>Charlotte Folk</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>To Pay</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" width="80">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10">
        <h6>CFXXI Sweater</h6>
        <h6>Large</h6>
        <h6>x1</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>P990</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg text-center bottom1"><a href="#">Contact Seller</a></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So, your `.container-fluid` elements should be aligned vertically down the page, instead of across the page?

Comment: it should be like this https://imgur.com/uzNzICN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap them inside a new div

```css
.content {
  display:flex;
}

aside {
border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

aside {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 350px;
}

aside ul {
 padding-top: 5%;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}

aside a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 23px;
 color: black;
 margin: 40px;
 font-family: $font1;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

aside a:hover {
 color: $color1;
}

.first {
  margin: 50px;
}
.first a {
  background-color: #ebe0dd;
  padding: 4px;
}

.line {
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $color5;
}

.rightDiv {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--Link for Font awesome icons-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/try.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class = "content">
    <aside class = "d-none d-md-block">
      <ul>
        <li class = "first"><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">To Pay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">To Ship</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">To Receive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Completed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cancelled</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    
    
  <div class='rightDiv'>
    <div class="container-fluid p-3 item1" height = "20">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
          <img src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" width="50">
        </div>
  
        <div class="col col-lg-10 my-2">
          <h5>Charlotte Folk</h5>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
          <h6>To Pay</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
          <img src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" width="80">
        </div>
  
        <div class="col col-lg-10">
          <h6>CFXXI Sweater</h6>
          <h6>Large</h6>
          <h6>x1</h6>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
          <h6>P990</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg text-center bottom1"><a href="#">Contact Seller</a></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  
    
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 item2" height = "20">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charrr.png" alt="" width="50">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10 my-2">
        <h5>Charlotte Folk</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>To Pay</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col col-lg-1 text-center">
        <img src="/images/charlottewhite.jpg" alt="" width="80">
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-10">
        <h6>CFXXI Sweater</h6>
        <h6>Large</h6>
        <h6>x1</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-lg-1 my-2 text-center">
        <h6>P990</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg text-center bottom1"><a href="#">Contact Seller</a></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>





  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend the two containers across the screen? because it only looks like it limits the containers in a half screen

Comment: Yes just give 100% width to new div and cancel the margins in container. You can give padding as well for the new div @Chris

Comment: Last question, how can i adjust the height of the containers (1st and 2nd)?

Comment: You can use height feature of css inside the main divs of the containers @Chris

Answer (score 0):

keep that `.content {display: flex}` but try to add a new container for that two price column or that two container you mentioned in question and then add this ruleset `.your-class { display:flex; flex-direction: column; }`